# permission denied error when using wechat js sdk on meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, wechat

Template.rendered:

```
var wxparams = {debug: false, jsApiList: ['chooseImage', 'uploadImage'], url: location.href};
    Meteor.call('GetJsConfig', wxparams, function (err, result) {
        if (!err && result) {
            alert(err);
            alert(result);
            wx.config(result);
            wx.ready(function () {
                alert('ready!~');
            });
            wx.error(function (res) {
                // config信息验证失败会执行error函数，如签名过期导致验证失败，具体错误信息可以打开config的debug模式查看，也可以在返回的res参数中查看，对于SPA可以在这里更新签名。
                alert('err!~：' + res.errMsg);
            });
        }
   });
```

Template.events:

```
'click .routeheadimg': function () {
        //alert('点击图片');
        wx.chooseImage({
            success: function (res) {
                Session.set('headimgId', res.localIds[0]); // 返回选定照片的本地ID列表，localId可以作为img标签的src属性显示图片
            },
            fail: function (res) {
                alert('choosefail:' + res.errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
```

The result of wx.config is OK.

wx.ready run success.

wx.error do not run.

wx.chooseImage result:{"errMsg":"system:permission denied"}

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have disabled phote/camera access for Wechat app, enable it in your system settings and it should work fine.